# Repeated sheet symbol with bus inputs and outputs

Tags: schematics, altium

Is there anyway to do this kind of thing in Circuit Studio/Altium Designer? 
[image: Repeated Device with multiple inputs and outputs]

This is just an example of the problem I'm having.

Specifically I am trying to use the Repeat command on a Sheet symbol that contains inputs and outputs that are already in bus format.

When I compile I get this error:

[Error] Sheet1.SchDoc   Compiler    Net OUT[1..2] contains multiple Output Sheet Entrys (Sheet Entry Device2-REPEAT(OUT1..2,Sheet Entry Device3-REPEAT(OUT1..2,Sheet Entry Device4-REPEAT(OUT1..2)

I understand that means that the outputs of all the instantiated devices are getting joined together, which is not what I want.

I would actually rather have all the inputs and outputs enumerated together like: IN[1..8] and OUT[1..8], but I couldn't get that to work either.

Comment: yes! you can make [multi-channel designs in CircuitStudio](http://documentation.circuitstudio.com/display/CSTU/WorkspaceManager_Dlg-ProjectPropertiesPage_MultiChannel((Project+Options+-+Multi-Channel))_CS).

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't work with the REPEAT statement. Place 4 instances of your Sheet Symbol and wire it up accordingly.